# What is the purpose of TWorkStealingQueue and how to use it?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, threadpool

I am working on a program to migrate files from potentially big directory structures and many of them (approx. 1 million).
My migration code already works quite well, and I am using a class to iterate to the directory structure, identify the files to migrate them sequentially one after another.

Now I want to make better use of the available CPU resources of the targeted machine, and do those migrations asynchronously grabbing threads from a `System.Threading.TThreadPool` to execute these.

I know well about the `ITask` interface, and how to make use of `TTask` to set up an array of tasks, that will be managed in conjunction with a `TThreadPool` instance.
Though setting up a big `TArray<ITask>` array, and waiting for completion when all the directories were walked through, just seems to be an inappropriate and inefficient approach (especially in regards of memory consumption).

What I believe I need there is just to have a simple thread safe *producer* / *consumer* queue, that grows and shrinks as worker threads are available to consume the tasks, and complete them.

Now I found something that sounds promising these regards at the Emba docs, called a [`TWorkStealingQueue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Threading.TWorkStealingQueue), but as so often, the documentation is pretty poor and lacks concise examples how to make use of it.

It would boil down to something like that

```
TMigrationFileWalker = class(TFileWalker) 
strict private
    var
       FPendingMigrationTasks : TArray<ITask>;

    function createMigrationTask(const filename : string) : ITask;
strict protected
    procedure onHandleFile(const filename : string); override;
public
    procedure walkDirectoryTree(const startDir : string); override;
end;

implementation

procedure TMigrationFileWalker.onHandleFile(const filename : string);
var
    migrationTask : ITask;
begin
    migrationTask := createMigrationTask(filename);
    self.FPendingMigrationTasks := self.FPendingMigrationTasks + [migrationTask];
    migrationTask.Start();
end;

procedure walkDirectoryTree(const startDir : string);
begin
    inherited walkDirectoryTree(startDir);
    TTask.WaitForAll(self.FPendingMigrationTasks,SOME_REASONABLE_TIMEOUT);
end;
```

Of course I could have a thread safe PC queue, and manage a bunch of threads working on it. But the promise there is it works with a thread pool, and I'd like to take advantage of the already available load balancing mechanisms coming with it.

Is anyone around here who already used `TWorkStealingQueue`, and can give a short, concise example how that could be used in such scenario as described above? Or at least clarify what's the actual purpose of that class, in case I totally misunderstood that from the naming?

A research about `TWorkStealingQueue` didn't yield any better results, than redirecting to the insufficient Embarcadero documentation.

Comment: At a WAG, it seems to be a Delphi implementation of work stealing, which seems to be a widely enough known to have an article on wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing.  Have you looked, f.i. at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jennifer/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0/?

Comment: @MartynA Well, I didn't know these articles yet. Thank you for mentioning. Thus that looks more like a specific OS adopted specialization to approach balanced queuing, rather than a general thread safe PC queue approach?

Comment: Tbh I hadn't come across work-stealing before you mentioned the component.  It might be worthwhile also asking here https://plus.google.com/communities/103113685381486591754, as the author of OmniThreadLibrary hangs out there https://www.thedelphigeek.com/

Comment: @MartynA I already did so of course: https://plus.google.com/113489861073154975115/posts/5d4ggRYQzAz

Comment: `TWorkStealingQueue` is used inside the same unit by `TThreadPool.TQueueWorkerThread` and directly by `TThreadPool`. That may help you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will delete it. Thanks